# Factoring and Simplifying

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to do this problem,

$$(4x + 1)^{15}\cdot\frac{1}{3}(12x - 5)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\cdot 12 + (12x - 5)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot15(4x + 1)^{14}\cdot 4$$

I've gotten down to,

$$4(4x+1)^{15}(12x-5)^{-\frac{2}{3}} + 60(12x-5)^{\frac{1}{3}}(4x+1)^{14}$$

I'm really wanting to understand how to finish this problem and the steps necessary from this point. Math isn't my strong suit. If you reply to this, I'd greatly appreciate an explanation/step by step. Thank you!

Comment: Please use latex to format your question, to make it comprehensible. (4x+1)^15(1/3)(12x - 5)^-2/3(12) could mean $(4x + 1)^{\frac{15}{3}}\cdot(12x - 5)^{12\cdot\frac{-2}{3}}$, or $(4x + 1)^15\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot(12x - 5)^{-2} / 3 \cdot 12$ or some thing different altogether.

Comment: (4x+1)^(15)(1/3)(12x-5)^(-2/3)(12) + (12x-5)^(1/3)(15)(4x+1)^(14)(4) ?

I don' t know how to convert it into a different format. =\

Comment: (4x+1)^15∙(1/3)∙(12x-5)^-(2/3)∙(12)+(12x-5)^(1/3)∙(15)∙(4x+1)^14∙(4)

Comment: You could write it out on a paper (or microsoft paint) and post it over here, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: http://i590.photobucket.com/albums/ss349/deutonus/mathproblem.png

Okay, i wrote it out on paint. Haha

Comment: There you go! Hope I edited it correctly.

Comment: Yes, that looks right! :)

Answer (score 2):

Force out the common factor of $(4x + 1)^{14} (12x - 5)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ to get

$$(4x + 1)^{14} (12x - 5)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left((4x + 1)\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot 12 + (12x - 5)\cdot 15 \cdot 4\right)$$

Which simplifies to

$$(4x + 1)^{14} (12x - 5)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(736x - 296)$$

Comment: When you factor out the -2/3 exponent, what happens to the 1/3 exponent?

Comment: You do $\frac{1}{3} = 1 - \frac{2}{3}$ and take out the $\frac{2}{3}$ to leave $1$.